# How do I post to GraphQL from PHP

Tags: php, curl, post, graphql

I have the following curl request to GraphQL. It works great, but in production `shell_exex` is not allowed. How do I re-write this curl post in valid PHP?

```php
 $curl_string = 'curl -g -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "' . AIRTABLE_API_KEY;
  $curl_second_string = ' -d \'{"query": "{fullCapaReview (id: \"' . $id . '\") {proposedRuleName submissionDate agencyContactName statusLawDept}}"}\' https://api.baseql.com/airtable/graphql/appXXXzzzzzzzzzz';
  $curl_complete_string = "$curl_string $curl_second_string";
  $result = shell_exec($curl_complete_string);
```

edit: I'm sorry, I put the wrong query. The query I had in mind was:

`' -d \'{"query": "{dMsAgencies (agencyAcronym: \"' . $_agency . '\") {agencyAcronym fullCapaReview { id }}}"}\'`

I make two similar calls. I will leave the original there because someone answered based on that.

This is what I have so far:

```php
$curl = curl_init($url);
$query = 'query dMsAgencies($agencyAcronym: String) {agencyAcronym fullCapaReview { id }} ';
$variables = ["agencyAcronym" => $id ];
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['query' => $query, 'variables' => $variables])); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer ' . AIRTABLE_API_KEY]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


console_log("Response : " . $response);
```

This is the error message I am getting. I just want to see if I am in the ballpark with my syntax.

```
Response : {"errors":[{"message":"Cannot query field \"agencyAcronym\" on type \"Query\".","locations":[{"line":1,"column":44}],"stack":["GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"agencyAcronym\" on type \"Query\"."," at Object.Field (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectTypeRule.js:46:31)"," at Object.enter (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:323:29)"," at Object.enter (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:370:25)"," at visit (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:243:26)"," at validate (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:69:24)"," at graphqlMiddleware (/var/app/current/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js:133:32)"," at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"]},{"message":"Variable \"$agencyAcronym\" is never used in operation \"dMsAgencies\".","locations":[{"line":1,"column":19}],"stack":["GraphQLError: Variable \"$agencyAcronym\" is never used in operation \"dMsAgencies\"."," at Object.leave (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/NoUnusedVariablesRule.js:38:33)"," at Object.leave (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:344:29)"," at Object.leave (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:390:21)"," at visit (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:243:26)"," at validate (/var/app/current/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:69:24)"," at graphqlMiddleware (/var/app/current/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js:133:32)"," at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"]}]}
```

`message":"Cannot query field \"agencyAcronym\" on type \"Query\"`

`{"message":"Variable \"$agencyAcronym\" is never used in operation \"dMsAgencies\".","locations":[{"line":1,"column":19}]`

Comment: Where did the `dMsAgencies` come from? Why the `query` variable different in both examples?

Answer (score 2):

The queries are not the same, but assuming that you are aware, your PHP example also has a syntax issue.

```
query dMsAgencies($agencyAcronym: String) {
    agencyAcronym 
    fullCapaReview { 
        id 
    }
}
```

If you compare this with the example in the [docs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) (when using variables) you can see that you are currently not using the `$agencyAcronym` variable anywhere (and there probably isn't a query named `agencyAcronym` in your schema). Here is one example (using the query from your first snippet):

```
query dMsAgencies($agencyAcronym: String) {
    fullCapaReview (id: $agencyAcronym) {
        proposedRuleName 
        submissionDate
        agencyContactName
        statusLawDept
    }
}
```